# how to open a specific tab in the accordion from another page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, external-links

Please help me with this issue. I am developing a website for my client link is http://richescarpentryandbuilding.com.au/ here you will get bounching css3 effect pictures and below the h2 heading. All i want when people click on h2 heading such as **Quality Builder**, **Residential Constructions**, **Commercial Installation** etc individual h2 heading will open the service page's http://richescarpentryandbuilding.com.au/service/ specific accordion tab such as "Quality Builder"  "Residential Constructions" "Commercial Installation" respectively. I have put the link but they are not working. I am novice in Javascript and Jquery. I am using below code for my accordion.....

```
$(function() {
    var myName = $('#name');
    myName.focus(function() { if ($(this).val() == 'NAME ...') {$(this).val('');} });
    myName.blur(function() { if ($(this).val() == '') {$(this).val('NAME ...');} });        
    var myEmail = $('#email');
    myEmail.focus(function() { if ($(this).val() == 'EMAIL ...') {$(this).val('');} });
    myEmail.blur(function() { if ($(this).val() == '') {$(this).val('EMAIL ...');} });          
    $('.top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
    $('.header nav ul ul li a').append('<span>&nbsp;</span>');
    $('.featured_list li a').append('<span class="zoom">&nbsp;</span>');

    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
$('#h_tabs div').hide();
$('#h_tabs div:first').show();
$('#h_tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
$('#h_tabs ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#h_tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab2 = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#h_tabs div').hide();
    $(currentTab2).show();
    return false;
});
$('#s_tabs div').hide();
$('#s_tabs div:first').show();
$('#s_tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
$('#s_tabs ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#s_tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab3 = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#s_tabs div').hide();
    $(currentTab3).show();
    return false;
});
$('.top_title, .text_bar2').prepend('<div class="text_bar_shadow"></div>').append('<div class="text_bar_shadow2"></div>');
$('.features_block ul li, .features2_block ul li, .bc_list ul li, .features5_block ul li, .services_option4 ul li, .small_icons ul li, .medium_icons ul li, .large_icons ul li').prepend('<span class="circle"></span>');
$('.faq_list .filter li').on('click', function(){
    $('.faq_list .filter li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('.faq_list .filter .all').on('click', function(){
    $('#faq .all').show();
});
$('.faq_list .filter .business').on('click', function(){
    $('#faq .technical').hide();
    $('#faq .miscellaneous').hide();
    $('#faq .business').show();
});
$('.faq_list .filter .technical').on('click', function(){
    $('#faq .business').hide();
    $('#faq .miscellaneous').hide();
    $('#faq .technical').show();
});
$('.faq_list .filter .miscellaneous').on('click', function(){
    $('#faq .business').hide();
    $('#faq .technical').hide();
    $('#faq .miscellaneous').show();
});
});
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the jQueryUI Accordion element, that's a ready to use accordion plugin with a extremely easy implementation.
You'll only need to import jQuery and the jQueryUI library for it to work, and you can then trigger it with a very simple jQuery initialization function.
You can find complete documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/